# Copy Activity in Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How can Azure Datafactory's copy activity be used to rename folders during the process of moving data from a datalake gen1 to a datalake gen2, in the following scenarios:

If the original folder structure in datalake gen1 is y=2022/m=08/d=01, and the desired structure in datalake gen2 is 2022/08/01, can the copy activity be configured to rename the folders accordingly?
I want to do it for all months and days of year.

Comment: yes, you can make the path datasets dynamic and have expressions in that

Answer (score 1):

- You can store the folder and file path details of source ADLS gen1 in a control table and use that as source dataset for lookup activity.

[image]

- Take a for-each activity, and connect it sequentially with lookup activity. In for-each activity, expression for item is given as
  `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
- Inside for-each activity, take a copy activity. Create a linked service for ADLS gen1 and create a dataset parameter for folder and file. In source dataset, pass `@item().Folder` as value to folder parameter and `@item().File` to file parameter.

[image]

- Similarly, create a sink dataset for ADLS gen2. Also, create dataset parameters for folder and file names.
- Pass  `@replace(replace(replace(item().Folder,'y=',''),'m=',''),'d=','')`  as a value to folder parameter. This will replace 'y=', 'm=' and 'd='
  from item().folder value. Pass `@item().file` to file parameter.

[image]

When pipeline is run, folders are renamed as per the requirement.

**Source File path: **
[image]

**Sink File Path:**
[image]

Comment: Hey, Aswin thanks for answering. I was looking to do it only through Azure data factory without having a dependency on tables.  There can be another way as well I guess for example, I could simply copy and chain python notebooks to rename it.

Comment: There is no direct option to dynamically rename the folders while copying in ADF.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your effort though for answering.

Comment: @Surya I have not accepted it cause there is no direct way of doing it. Please read the above comments